# jqgrid column chooser, how to add id attribute to 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons

Tags: jqgrid

How can i add id attribute to the buttons 'Ok' and 'Cancel' in jqgrid column chooser dialog.

```
onClickButton: function () {
                                    $(table).jqGrid('columnChooser', {
                                            done: function (perm) {
                                                if (perm) {
                                                       $(table).jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
```